# What's difference between Multichain, Chain, Hyperledger, Ethereum etc

Tags: blockchain, alternatives

I stumbled upon multiple Blockchain protocols framework. For example Multichain http://www.multichain.com/

What's difference between this one and the others ?

Comment: There are any differences with regard to security, centralization, access, features, purpose, etc. You should ask a more specific question if you want a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Multichain is directly built from Bitcoin Core which power the bitcoins. Of course there are modifications to it. Multichain provides direct interface with many parameters and is basically used to make permissioned networks.  And the major difference between multichain and other blockchain technologies is no use of smart contracts in multichain.

Also, Bitcoin is open network, Ethereum allows public network apps, hyperledger is used for building private blockchains and multichain for permissioned blockchains.